# Insert data to magento table

Tags: magento

I am fuzzy on magento concepts. I have created one custom module(Simply we can say magento extension). I have constructed new table for this extension. Now I want to insert data to this custom table.

I am thinking that which is better to write insert command on

```
             `Model/file.php`
```

or

```
             `Model/Resource/file.php`?
```

1. Which is better and explain me?

And one more question is

shall I call `Model` directly from `block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the default Magento way is to write the queries in the Resource files and  `Model/File.php` has also the function that calls the Resource function.
Model function will be as following:

```
public function doSomething($params)
{

    return $this->_getResource()->doSomething($params);
    //the doSomething used here should be declared in Resource file
}
```

and then the function called by the `$this->_getResource()` should be declared in Resource file `Model/Resource/File.php` as following:

```
public function doSomething($params)
{
    //Here comes your custom queries.
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select().......

    return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
}
```

and you can call this Model function anywhere, in Blocks,helper,controllers etc

Comment: Ok... shall I directly call model's function in block/file.php?

Comment: Why we are using Adapter??

Comment: You asked the best practice so this as how Magento works. also updated the answer for your second question

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the ticket, :) it will help others